# PHP error: "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given"

Tags: php, sql

There isnt an actual error, but it's still displaying an error message when a user who is not the buyer or seller goes to the page. Is it possible to suppress the error message?

Direct link to images

- http://i37.tinypic.com/2m5ijvq.jpg
- http://i36.tinypic.com/148kads.jpg

[image]

[image]

```
  //transaction id
$transactionid = $_GET['id'];

//Retrieve info about transaction
$query = "SELECT ads.*, feedback.*, transactions.* FROM (ads INNER JOIN transactions ON ads.id=transactions.ad_id) INNER JOIN feedback ON transactions.id=feedback.transaction_id WHERE transaction_id = '$transactionid'";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
$seller = $row['seller'];
$buyer = $row['buyer'];

//check if user is buyer or seller
if ($_SESSION['user_id'] == $seller) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE transaction_id = '$transactionid' AND seller_comment IS NULL";
    $data1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
} else if ($_SESSION['user_id'] == $buyer) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE transaction_id = '$transactionid' AND buyer_comment IS NULL";
    $data1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
}

//if user is buyer/seller echo form to them to submit feedback
if (mysqli_num_rows($data1) == 1) {
    echo '<p><form method="post" action="feedback.php?id=' . $transactionid . '&action=submitfeedback">
    <textarea id="feedback" name="feedback" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></form></p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>feedback already given</p>';
}
```

Comment: you have an if/else if which means that in some cases (although I did not look hard) you may end up not executing either query and thus end up with no query performed and then mysql_num_rows has nothing to check which could cause your problem.  I would suggestion either adding an else just in case neither of the two execute OR placing the mysql_num_rows call into the if/else if blocks.  The latter may be bad practice beucase you would have a duplicated block of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to resolve the warning, not just cover it up.  You should be able to resolve this by changing the if statement to:

```
if(!empty($data1) && mysql_num_rows($data1) == 1) {
```

The problem is trying to pass NULL to the mysql function.

Comment: Its a FALSE not a NULL btw. Your code works either way though.

Comment: Simon, thanks for the clarification. While you are correct the value is FALSE, the DB is interpreting it as NULL as indicated by the warning.

Answer (score 1):

What if `$_SESSION['user_id']` does not equal `$seller` OR `$buyer`.  Then `$data1` never gets set and is null when passed into `num_rows`.

To suppress it put an @ before the function, like:

```
@mysqli_num_rows(...)
```

OR check for `!$data` before you do the `num_rows`:

```
if(!$data) {
    // not a buyer or seller
} else {
    // do the mysqli_num_rows
}
```

I would do the latter, it is much cleaner and clear.

Comment: +1: The root of the problem is an imperfectly designed program flow.

Comment: Suppression is not a very good coding practice. The idea behind the warning is so we can fix the issues.

Comment: The error supression is _really_ silly - it irritates me to no end in code I have to use.
If you want to stop errors from breaking the output, follow JCD's suggestion, don't use the `@`-method.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting something like the following in your php.ini file:

```
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = "error.log"
```

This will suppress error messages from being displayed on pages and instead output them to a logfile.

Comment: -1 That hides the error, yes. However, it's like saying "if there's a gas leak, use air freshener to cover up the smell." Both the smell and the warning message have a reason, namely, to alert you that there is a problem, and that it should be fixed to prevent bigger problems in the future. Fix the cause, not the symptoms.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I should have included that these settings should only be used in a production environment.

Answer (score -3):

### Try

```
@mysqli_num_rows
```

@ suppresses errors for that function

### However

it is best to remove the source of the error.

```
if (false !== $data1 && 1 === mysqli_num_rows($data1)) {
  // submit comment
} else {
  // comment already submitted
}
```

Comment: Hiding error messages instead of solving the underlying problem is not a good idea.

Comment: Bad idea. He should sort out the root of the problem.